# Sequence of $L^{2}$ functions satisfying an integral condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am working on the following problem: Suppose $f \in C^{\infty}([0, \infty) \times [0, 1])$ is such that $$C :=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|\partial_{t}f|^{2}(1 + t^{2})\, dx\, dt < \infty.$$ The problem is to show that there exists a $g \in L^{2}([0, 1])$ such that $f(t, \cdot)$ converges to $g(\cdot)$ in $L^{2}([0, 1])$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

By completeness of $L^{2}$, it would suffice to show that $f(t_{n}, \cdot)$ is Cauchy for each sequence $\{t_{n}\}$ tending to $\infty$. I can only derive the following result: Fix $h$. I will show that $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\|f(s, x) - f(s + h, x)\|_{L^{2}} = 0$. Fix an $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $N$ such that $hC/(1 + N^{2}) < \varepsilon$. Then for $s + h > s \geq N$,
\begin{align*}
\|f(s, x) - f(s + h, x)\|_{L^{2}}^{2} &= \int_{0}^{1}|f(s, x) - f(s + h, x)|^{2}\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}\left|\int_{s}^{s + h}\partial_{t}f\, dt\right|^{2}\, dx\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{s}^{s + h}|\partial_{t}f|\, dt\right)^{2}\, dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}h\int_{s}^{s + h}|\partial_{t}f|^{2}\, dt\, dx\\
& \leq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{s}^{s + h}h|\partial_{t}f|^{2}\frac{1 + t^{2}}{1 + t^{2}}\, dt\, dx \leq \frac{hC}{1 + N^{2}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
where in the last $\leq$ we used that $s \geq N$. Is there a way to remove the dependence of $N$ on $h$? If I could do that then the above calculation will show the result. Is there another way to do this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks basically fine to me, but I think we want to wrap it up as follows:
$$
\int_0^1 dx\,\left| \int_s^{s+h} dt\,|\partial_t f| (1+t^2)^{1/2}(1+t^2)^{-1/2} \right|^2 \le\\
\int_0^1 dx\, \int_s^{s+h} dt\, |\partial_t f|^2 (1+t^2) \int_s^{s+h} dt\, (1+t^2)^{-1} \le C\int_s^{\infty}dt\, \int_0^1 dx\, |\partial_t f|^2 (1+t^2) ,
$$
and this last (double) integral now goes to zero as $s\to\infty$.